# Scrolling (and eventually zooming) an SVG viewport

Tags: html, angular, svg, scroll

I have a graph rendered as SVG by Angular in a web page. The size of the SVG is dynamic, with its width being 100% of its container. I'd like to be able to scroll (and eventually zoom) the SVG's viewport. I'm not talking about the browser scrolling, but rather manually implemented scrolling by dragging on the background of the SVG.

I know I can use `viewBox` to do this, and changing the first two numbers works well, but the problem is that the second two numbers need to match the CSS width and height to be at 100% zoom. How do I work around this? Do I constantly need to update `viewBox` in response to the container size changing (e.g. when the browser window changes size) so it matches the CSS size?

There are many similar questions on here, but none that I can see are about this specific issue.

**Update:** I think I solved the first part of the problem using:

```
<svg #svg attr.viewBox="{{-scrollX}} {{-scrollY}} {{svg.clientWidth}} {{svg.clientHeight}}">
```

But I'm a little suspicious of its efficiency.

I still need to figure out how `MouseEvent` coordinates interact with this to be able to update my `scrollX` and `scrollY`, as well as how to make the SVG grow bigger as it needs to (but not bigger on the screen).

Comment: I think you can use percentages in the viewBox, if not then yeah i think you need to resort to getting the viewBounds of box on resize events

Comment: The ``viewBox`` specifies where SVG **content** is drawn; so the ``viewBox`` takes numbers only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox